# NestJS | Passport: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logIn')

Tags: passport.js, nest

Situation:

- Developing api in nest & grapqhql
- Worked on one laptop, everything was working well
- Then cloned my repo on other laptops, installed dependencies, created a new local database.
- App is being built with no errors
- When following localhost:4000 in browser to open graphql playground I'm receiving 500 error end next message:

  ```
  ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logIn')
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logIn')
      at authenticate (/home/gleb/Projects/artwine-api/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:96:21)
      at /home/gleb/Projects/artwine-api/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:91:3
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at /home/gleb/Projects/artwine-api/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:83:83
      at JWTAccessAuthGuard.<anonymous> (/home/gleb/Projects/artwine-api/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:49:36)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (/home/gleb/Projects/artwine-api/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:17:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  ```

Code of a passport lib function where the error is caught:

```
return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    req.login =
    req.logIn = req.logIn || IncomingMessageExt.logIn;
    req.logout =
    req.logOut = req.logOut || IncomingMessageExt.logOut;
    req.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated || IncomingMessageExt.isAuthenticated;
    req.isUnauthenticated = req.isUnauthenticated || IncomingMessageExt.isUnauthenticated;
    
    req._sessionManager = passport._sm;
..............
```

Link to the repo: https://github.com/Gleb-Gaiduk/artwine-api
Any ideas on what could go wrong after cloning the working repository?

Comment: Did you ever find out the issue?

Comment: Wondering the same, facing this exception as well...

Comment: @Frey https://stackoverflow.com/a/71707298/425226

Answer (score 19):

You need to transform the ExecutionContext from Graphql to one Nestjs/Passport can read: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/other-features#execution-context

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class MySuperGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req;
  }
}
```

Comment: more specifically, this part of the docs:

https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#graphql

The current typings don't include `getRequest` though.

Comment: This solution is now [included in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport#graphql).

Answer (score 7):

try adding this into "subscriptions" section of GraphQL module initialization:

```
'subscriptions-transport-ws': {
    onConnect: (headersRaw: Record<string, unknown>) => {
        // Lowercase each header key
        const headers = Object.keys(headersRaw).reduce((dest, key) => {
            dest[key.toLowerCase()] = headersRaw[key];
            return dest;
        }, {});
        return {
            req: {
                headers: headers,
            },
        };
    },
},
```

I have no idea why it is not documented, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You should look your Guard and strategy you are using and should handle errors from there for example:

```
@Injectable()
export class PassportLocalGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
protected readonly logger = new Logger(PassportLocalGuard.name);

canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
const { req } = ctx.getContext();

return super.canActivate(new ExecutionContextHost([req]));
   }

handleRequest(err: any, user: any) {
  if (err) {
   this.logger.error(`Auth Error! ${err.message}`);
   throw err;
   }

  if (!user) {
   this.logger.error('Auth Error! User not found');
   throw new AuthenticationError('Auth Error! User not found');
   }

  return user;
 }
}
```