# Nestjs Subscription Graphql authenication

Tags: node.js, nestjs

The nestjs Graphql subscription not working on resolvers with guard.

````
```{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logIn')",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "bookingCreated"
      ]
    }
  ]
}```
````

Comment: The answer in this link solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70644923/nestjs-passport-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-logi/71771845#71771845

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why this was not in the documentation but gratefully this solved my issues [NestJS | Passport: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logIn')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70644923/nestjs-passport-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-logi/71771845#71771845)